# Characteristic subgroups of $p$-groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group. Suppose that $G$ has only one characteristic subgroup(nontrivial proper). What possible structures does $G$ have?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at :

S. P. Glasby, P. P. Pálfy, Csaba Schneider, p-Groups with a unique proper non-trivial characteristic subgroup,  Journal of Algebra, Volume 348,Pages 85-109

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869311005552